# Slack integration like Giphy, that responds from the user instead of from a Bot

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm attempting to create a new slack command integration that when invoked will fetch a unique set of data for the user. I have the integration working, however the data returned is displayed within slack as a "BOT".

Ideally, the integration will be similar to Giphy. When the /giphy command in slack is invoked, an image is returned that is appended to the user's message. I'd be curious to know how they did this. As far as I can tell, Slack integration APIs only allow responses to be sent as BOTs not as a user or appended to a user's message.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is impossible, but note that the Giphy integration was actually built by the Slack team (or at least enjoys special privileges). So for example even on a completely new Slack team that doesn't have any integrations installed, typing `/giphy` will prompt you to install Giphy. This is a privilege that normal third party slack apps do not have.